# Can "A, B, and so on" be used as a subject?

Tags: usage

Can "A, B, and so on" be used as a subject?
Also, how about "A, B, etc."?

For example, are the following sentences correct?

> Baseball, soccer, and so on are my favorite sports.

> Baseball, soccer, etc. are my favorite sports.

Comment: Have you been taught how to diagram out sentences? What do you think is the subject in your examples?

Comment: "Baseball, soccer, and so on"/"Baseball, soccer, etc." are subjects.

Comment: You are correct, in each example those are the plural subjects.

Answer (score 0):

These phrases can be used as subjects, but if you are trying to write clearly you should not use them.

What does "and so on" mean in "Baseball, soccer and so on"?  It should be easy for me to complete your list from the context. But I have no idea what other sports you think are similar to baseball and soccer.  Is it "cricket"? Is it "sumo wrestling"? Is it "tiddlywinks"?

Adding "and so on" makes your sentence meaningless!